# laravel 7 Get Sum From eloquent relation column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

```
 $user = User::with(['affiliateCode','rewardPoints','orders'=>function($query){
        $query->where('order_status_id','!=',1);
    }])
    ->withCount(['orders'=>function($q){
        $q->where('order_status_id','!=',1);   
    }])
    ->where('id',$userId)->first();
```

The above code is working fine.. I also want to return `sum` of all `amount` from `orders` table where `order_status_id !=1` with this response..

i have tried `withSum()` but its not working since its laravel 7,
can anyone help to to return the sum also.? Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `withCount` method with callback like this.

```
$user = User::with(['affiliateCode','rewardPoints','orders'=>function($query){
        $query->where('order_status_id','!=',1);
    }])
    ->withCount(['orders'=>function($q){
        $q->where('order_status_id','!=',1);   
    }])
    ->withCount(['orders as orders_amount'=>function($q){
        $q->where('order_status_id','!=',1)->select(DB::raw('sum(amount)'));   
    }])
    ->where('id',$userId)->first();
```

Comment: In newer version there is a new helper available to get sum from relation [withSum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Yes I know but he is doing it in laravel 7.